# MultiSelect TreeView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, multi-select

I am new to WPF, I have to create multiselect treeview in WPF, I have found article 
[WPF TreeView with Multiple Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163801/wpf-treeview-with-multiple-selection?answertab=active#tab-top) , but I am not sure where to write. Do I need to write this code inside SelectedItemChanged event handler? Please advise.

Answer (score -3):

You just need to call this method from the constructor of your window class after InitializeComponent().