# TreeView: child node's VM being affected by parent selection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, datatemplate

What's wrong with the following TreeView setup? Setting `selected` property of parent node's VM toggles child node's `selected` property.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}">
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding selected}" />
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding descriptions}">
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding selected}" />
        </Style>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The VM objects look like this:

```
public class DocumentVM : ObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
      get { return _name; }
      set { Set(ref _name, value); }
    }

    private bool _selected = false;
    public bool selected
    {
      get { return _selected; }
      set { Set(ref _selected, value); }
    }
}
```

`DescriptionVM` is very similar.

So for example, if I run the following two lines:

```
MyVM.Documents[1].descriptions[0].selected = true;
MyVM.Documents[1].selected = true;
```

First line sets first child of second document to selected, whereas the second line sets first document node to select, but **sets first child of second document to unselected**. I'm sure this is something wrong with the DataTemplates I'm using there, but can't figure out what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the WPF TreeView doesn't support multiple selection, so the second select will automatically unselect the first item.

There are ways to handle this - look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6681993/967885).

Comment: aaaaaah. Why in the world this didn't occur to me? Thanks a lot.