# Retaining TreeViewItem formatting while using virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm currently trying to implement virtualization in a modified TreeView that enables multi-select. Starting with the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18751667/4830695), I added the following attribute to the "multiSelectTreeView" element.

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
```

However, now that I've done this, I've noticed that the treeview 'forgets' the formatting of the selected items whenever I scroll away from them and return. I thought that this might be fixed by setting the VirtualizationMode to 'Standard' but this hasn't worked. Does anyone have an idea of what I should try next?