# How to visually show multiselect on TreeView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm attempting to enable a `TreeView` control to support multi select.

The very basic flow works, if you select multiple items in the `TreeView` while holding down ctrl or shift then it will successfully add those items to a list I have in the view model.

The problem is that when actually clicking on the `TreeView` items it will only select one visually i.e. only one item is marked as selected. How can I make it highlight/mark multiple items? I don't understand where this is controlled.

The `TreeView` xaml:

```
<TreeView x:Name="availableColumnsTreeView" 
              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="availableColumnsTreeView"
              x:Uid="availableColumnsTreeView"           
              SelectedItemChanged="availableColumnsTreeView_SelectedItemChanged"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeFieldData, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SortingConverter}, ConverterParameter='DisplayName.Text'}"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Grid.Row="0">

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Uid="HierarchicalDataTemplate_1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SortingConverter}, ConverterParameter='DisplayName.Text'}">
            <TextBlock x:Uid="TextBlock_1" Text="{Binding DisplayName.Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

So "availableColumnsTreeView_SelectedItemChanged" is invoked fine, but I need it to actually highlight the selected items.

EDIT: Please read my question before marking it as a duplicate. I tried to be as specific as possible to what my problem is. I'm not looking for a whole solution for multi select hidden away in some one drive document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing the TreeView to allow multi select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459375/customizing-the-treeview-to-allow-multi-select)

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg I had a look at that, and went in another way to do it. But stuck now with the problem descrived in my question

Comment: *"add those items to a list"* - instead of having extra list you could use extra property of item itself to store selection and simply synchronize it (the place where you add/remove items to this selection list). As bonus you then have property which can be used in data template to do something (to run trigger, to change background, etc.).

Comment: @Sinatr I'm not sure if I 100% follow you. Could provide a small example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I 100% follow you. Could provide a small example please?

Sure.

Here is xaml:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, Mode=OneWay}">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}">
                <CheckBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                </DataTrigger.Setters>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And here is cs:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Children { get; set; }

    bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSelected)));
        }
    }

    public Item(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item("1") { Children = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item("11"),
            new Item("12"),
            new Item("13"),
        }},
        new Item("2") { Children = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item("11"),
            new Item("12"),
            new Item("13"),
        }},
        new Item("3"),
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

I am using `CheckBox` to select item (no idea how you do it). If item is selected it has its foreground changed to red via data trigger.

As you can see selection (disregards how you implement it, really, I am using single selection `TreeView`) is stored inside items as `IsSelected` value. You can traverse hierarchical collection to get a list of selected items (this is called *flattering*).

Note: `IPropertyChanged`, it's required if you plan to set `IsSelected` from code-behind (e.g. select all items on button press).

It should be easy to adapt to your case.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it highlight/mark multiple items? I don't understand where this is controlled.

You define the appearance of a `TreeViewItem` container using a `TreeViewItem` style. If you add an "IsSelected" property to your data object that keeps track of whether the item is currently selected, you could use a `DataTrigger` that binds to this one and provide the highlighting, e.g.:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    ...
</TreeView>
```

Make sure that the data class where the "IsSelected" property is defined implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and that you set this property in your event handler or command.