# Create WPF windows explorer tree view with checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, file-browser

I'm trying to create a WPF windows explorer tree view file browser with check boxes for select multiple files. Check boxes should view only for the files.
Like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiBMh.png)

I don`t have a lot experience in WPF it quite difficult for me to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, you can check this answer, and customize it for your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18751667/12655548

Comment: I have created treeview according this example https://medium.com/@mikependon/designing-a-wpf-treeview-file-explorer-565a3f13f6f2 . But how to add check boxes for the files and get selected files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customizing the TreeView to allow multi select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459375/customizing-the-treeview-to-allow-multi-select)

Comment: Seems like author found some other source code as an example

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the simplest idea, on how it could be implemented. Considering two classes `Folder` and `File` (I've implemented my own simple classes fot the ease of the example):

```
public class Folder
{
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; } = new();

    public List<File> Files { get; set; } = new();


    public override string ToString() => Name;
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

You would have this kind of `MultiselectTreeView` implementation:

```
public class MultiSelectTree: TreeView
{
    public List<File> SelectedFiles { get; set; } = new();
    
    public void AddItem(object item)
    {
        if (item is Folder folder)
        {
            var root = FormFolderTreeItem(folder);
            Items.Add(root);
        }

        if (item is File file)
        {
            var f = FormFileTreeItem(file);
            Items.Add(f);
        }
    }

    private TreeViewItem FormFolderTreeItem(Folder folder)
    {
        var treeItem = new TreeViewItem { Header = folder };

        foreach (var subFolderItem in folder.Folders.Select(FormFolderTreeItem))
        {
            treeItem.Items.Add(subFolderItem);
        }

        foreach (var file in folder.Files.Select(FormFileTreeItem))
        {
            treeItem.Items.Add(file);
        }
        
        return treeItem;
    }
    
    private TreeViewItem FormFileTreeItem(File file)
    {
        var treeItem = new TreeViewItem ();
        // wrap Files in a checkbox and set this checkbox as a content of a TreeViewItem
        var checkBox = new CheckBox { Content = file };
        treeItem.Header = checkBox;
        
        // Subscribe for the checked event
        // When the event triggers - add file to the SelectedFiles
        checkBox.Checked += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (sender is CheckBox chb)
            {
                SelectedFiles.Add((File)chb.Content);
            }
            args.Handled = true;
        };
        
        // Just the opposite here
        checkBox.Unchecked += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (sender is CheckBox chb)
            {
                SelectedFiles.Remove((File)chb.Content);
            }
            args.Handled = true;
        };

        return treeItem;
    }
}
```

You can then access you selected files with `SelectedFiles` property.

Here is the example of the usage (Tree is the instance of `MultiSelectTree`):

```
var firstRoot = new Folder { Name = "Root" };
var secondRoot = new Folder {Name = "Second Root"};
        
firstRoot.Folders.Add(new Folder { Name = "Sub folder"});
        
secondRoot.Files.AddRange(new []
{
     new File {Name = "First file" },
     new File {Name = "Second file" }
});
        
Tree.AddItem(firstRoot);
Tree.AddItem(secondRoot);
```

As a result you will have this: [TreeView with checkboxes and multiselect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6lCU.png)

Now you'll have to figure out how to adjust the example that you've already used in [Designing a WPF TreeView File Explorer](https://medium.com/@mikependon/designing-a-wpf-treeview-file-explorer-565a3f13f6f2)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I learned something from you example and I did it another way. Your method couldn't apply to the my tree viewer.I Added check box <CheckBox  Visibility="{Binding CheckVisibility}"  Checked="TreeView_Checked" Unchecked="TreeView_Checked" /> and passed relevant values.